# Jpype.startjvm not working for iOS but works for Windows

Tags: python, jpype

This command, and the program it's part of, works on my Windows laptop but not on my MacBook Pro.  It's supposed to allow me to setup the JVM to use two classes at once.

**This doesn't work in iOS but does in Windows:**
jpype.startJVM(JVMHome, "-Djava.awt.headless=true", '-Djava.class.path=%s' % oracleJarPath +';'+ mincronJarPath)

But if I change it just to a single path it works for either one.  Does anyone know what's wrong or what I should do differently?

**This works for both:**
jpype.startJVM(JVMHome, "-Djava.awt.headless=true", '-Djava.class.path=%s' % oracleJarPath)

Comment: This question needs editing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the character to separate the paths is different.  For Windows it's ";" but for the iOS it's ":".  Looks like I just need to figure out how to take advantage of the os.path.pathsep.join function.

More ...

Changing the code to this fixed the issue and made it work on both systems.

```
myPath = "-Djava.class.path="
myPath += os.path.pathsep.join([oracleJarPath,mincronJarPath])

jpype.startJVM(JVMHome, "-Djava.awt.headless=true", myPath)
```

Answer to this question, "Is -cp option not working in JPype?", helped solve the issue.